# How to use values from if else statements

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, jbutton

I created global variables lyk `int scor = 3, int fail = 0`, then turned them to strings using `Integer.toString()` method. I created an array of 10 buttons and used `if` statements to access their actions. My problem is that I used the variables `scor, fail` in each `if` statement. I want to at the end grab all the values of `scor, fail` for each button and add them up. My code is so large I could not paste it here. I need your help.

Comment: I don't understand this code example. There are so much errors especially with the brackets and the indentation... If you want to get help you should take the time to write a proper question with clean code snippets...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably downvoted because you didn't take the time to write down your _actual code_. It's very difficult to understand what you're trying to do. For example, you shouldn't sprinkle ellipsis (triple dots) all over your text - write complete sentences instead.

Comment: Text was hard to read because of ellipses "...". Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just simply make an array list of scores and fails and push back however many buttons. Then you can iterate through each button and set the distinctive values of both container elements using an index.

This will also solve your large block of if statements problem.

DrStrange.

Comment: Can u use a syntax for example!

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size())

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size(); i++) then you use an if statement: If (buttons[i].isPressed()) for example - scores[i] = new_score;